# Ruby on Rails Active Record Associations inherited attributes

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

So I am working on my very first ROR application, and am one task away from calling it done (for now of course). The application processes background checks for a Casino.  There is an Applicant Model, and an Investigation model.  In the investigation model I used applicant_id as my foreign key and linked them with a one to one relationship. Every applicant has one background check every background check has one applicant. I think my logic is correct.

Now on my show view I would like to display more information about the applicant that participated in the background check. Like applicant.first_name I can't find anything on how to print that information. Thanks

can I do

```
 investigation.applicant_first_name
```

I just don't know the syntax thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your controller and model all set up:

```
<% @investigation.applicants.each do |applicant| %>
<p>
  <%= applicant.first_name %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I am only doing one at a time on the show page. Basically all of the data that went into the check has to be on this one page. Like applicant first name and last name etc

Comment: @investigation.applicant.first_name?

Comment: You are on the investigations show page? If so, if you only have one applicant associated with that investigation, it should only show the first_name of the applicant even though we are doing an each. As you cycle through the the attributes you will reuse applicant => applicant.first_name; applicant.last_name, etc.

Comment: Now I am getting an error undefined method applicants thats a problem in my controller huh? Sorry I am a super noob just started a couple weeks ago

Comment: Also you mentioned a one to one relationship going both ways but it has to be declared only one way; belongs_to :investigation , has_one :applicant

Comment: honestly under show in the controller it is blank, and the specs actually said applicants can have many cases since I guess businesses apply for multiple different checks so I changed it to belongs_to applicant has_many: investigations

Comment: I told you I really don't know what I am doing with this rails stuff lol im a nooooooooob to programming to. I just took a few classes on js, but this client wanted user login and all this functionality and I was flirting with the idea of learning rails at the time so I told my boss thats what I wanted to do it in

Comment: Oh I get it in the controller @applicant = investigation.applicant_id in the controller???? Do you think that is right?

Comment: your investigations_controller for def show should be something like: @investigation = Investigation.find(params[:id]). When you get a chance read through this tutorial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: I have seen that before in the tutorials I just forgot how to do it